# Chrome Extension: Open New Popup Window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Could someone shed some light on where this code is incorrect please

```html
<script>
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(window) {
        chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(enumerated string ["popup"]) {
            chrome.windows.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('redirect.html')}, function(window) {
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to achieve that when the extension is clicked on a new popup window will load.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need a listener, just create it right away:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
   chrome.windows.create({'url': 'redirect.html', 'type': 'popup'}, function(window) {
   });
});
```

Comment: That creates a standard window, I wish to create a pop-up window.
(The one that doesn't display the URL bar etc)

Comment: Thank you!
One last thing (if you could help) Setting a width and height value, would that be listed inside the {} or separate?

Comment: @Daniel just look at the API docs, all parameters are listed there: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/windows.html

Comment: @serg Hello - Again - Could you lend a hand over here please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345435/pop-up-window-center-screen

Comment: thanks serg working on this now, checking the specific doc you listed as well.

Comment: Which file is this supposed to be in?