# Pop-Up Window, Center Screen

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using the following code to open a pop-up window in a Google Chrome extension, my one question is, how do I get the pop-up window to open in the centre of the users screen?

```
 <script>
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2); 
  chrome.windows.create({'url': 'redirect.html', 'type': 'popup', 'width': 440, 'height': 220, 'left': '+left+', 'top': '+top+', } , function(window) {
   });
});
  </script>
```

I've also tried this, which resulted in no such luck.

```
  <script>
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.windows.create({'url': 'redirect.html', 'type': 'popup', 'width': 440, 'height': 220, 'left': (screen.width/2)-(w/2), 'top': (screen.height/2)-(h/2), } , function(window) {
   });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: One issue I see: What are w and h? They aren't defined in either snippet

Comment: @Matt S I thought they were defined by: **'width': 440, 'height': 220,**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you see `var obj = {property: value}` structure in JS it is an object creation. In your code you are trying to pass an object containing window properties to `chrome.windows.create()` function.

Correct code should be:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    var w = 440;
    var h = 220;
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2); 

    chrome.windows.create({'url': 'redirect.html', 'type': 'popup', 'width': w, 'height': h, 'left': left, 'top': top} , function(window) {
    });
});
```

Comment: chrome.windows.create expect 'top' and 'left' to be integers so make sure to Math.round() before passing parameters.

Comment: This is a great solution! I posted one below that takes dual monitors into account as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the centering to also work with a dual monitor, you'll need to get the current window object from the extension and center your popup relative to that. Like so:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {
        var width = 440;
        var height = 220;
        var left = ((screen.width / 2) - (width / 2)) + win.left;
        var top = ((screen.height / 2) - (height / 2)) + win.top;

        chrome.windows.create({
            url: 'redirect.html',
            width: width,
            height: height,
            top: Math.round(top),
            left: Math.round(left),
            type: 'popup'
        });
     });
  });
```

`chrome.windows.create` expects an integer for `top` and `left`, so it is recommended to wrap those values in `Math.round`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the screen to appear in the middle of the browser (not the center of the screen), and dynamic window size, you can do this.

```js
chrome.windows.getCurrent((tabWindow) => {
  const width = Math.round(tabWindow.width * 0.5) // dynamic width
  const height = Math.round(tabWindow.height * 0.75) // dynamic height
  const left = Math.round((tabWindow.width - width) * 0.5 + tabWindow.left)
  const top = Math.round((tabWindow.height - height) * 0.5 + tabWindow.top)

  chrome.windows.create( // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create
    {
      focused: true,
      url: targetURL,
      type: 'popup', // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#type-WindowType
      width, height,
      left, top
    },
    (subWindow) => {}
  )
})
```

| Desc | Image |
| --- | --- |
| Show you what is the `tabWindow.top` and `left` | [image] |

And you can use some filters to check whether the window has been created or not, to determine to create a new one, or show the window that you made.

```js
chrome.windows.getAll({populate : true, windowTypes:['popup']}, (windowArray)=>{})
```

### example code

```js
chrome.windows.getCurrent((tabWindow) => { // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#type-Window
  const targetURL = 'yourTemplates/yourFile.html'
  chrome.windows.getAll({populate : true, windowTypes:['popup']}, (windowArray)=>{
    const queryURL = `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/${targetURL}`
    const target = windowArray.find(item=>item.tabs[0].url === queryURL) // ❗ make sure manifest.json => permissions including "tabs"
    if (windowArray.length > 0 && target !== undefined) {
      // Show the window that you made before.
      chrome.windows.update(target.id, {focused: true}) // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-update
      return
    }

    // Otherwise, Create
    const width = Math.round(tabWindow.width * 0.5)
    const height = Math.round(tabWindow.height * 0.75)
    const left = Math.round((tabWindow.width - width) * 0.5 + tabWindow.left)
    const top = Math.round((tabWindow.height - height) * 0.5 + tabWindow.top)

    chrome.windows.create( // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create
      {
        focused: true,
        url: targetURL,
        type: 'popup', // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#type-WindowType
        width, height,
        left, top
      },
      (subWindow) => {
      }
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to this answer, if you want to retrieve popup dimensions from localstorage--which are saved as strings--this will convert the variables to the necessary integers for the pop-up to work.

```
 var w =  parseInt(localStorage.getItem('key'));
 var h =  parseInt(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```